# symfony IBAN form field validation

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to use symfony validation for particular element using validateValue

Here is my code

```
$ibanConstraint = new IbanValidator();
$ibanConstraint->message = 'Invalid IBAN';
$errorList = $this->_validator->validateValue($form->get('iban')->getData(), $ibanConstraint);
```

But it throws exception like

> ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Validator\ConstraintValidatorFactory::getInstance() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint, instance of Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\IbanValidator given,

May i know what is the issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `IbanValidator` is validator (as it is said in its name). But in Validator component you don't need another validator. You need only constraint to validate with.

You should create your `$ibanConstraint` with constraint object:

```
$ibanConstraint = new Iban();
```